# The multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

MS SQL server 2008 r2

Trying to create a sql function that uses a table variable. It keeps throwing an error when i try to create the function. It either complains that i need to declare the scalar variable @LocationUpdate, or if i use a table alias LU it complains that the multi-part identifier lu.ID can not be bound.

Anyone know what i'm doing wrong? I have a sql statement before this one that inserts into the table variable and it's not throwing any errors on that. I have a feeling i'm doing something stupid-obvious but I'm not seeing it.

```
DECLARE @LocationUpdate TABLE (
[ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[FacilityName] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
[TrialUpdateID] [int] NOT NULL,
[StatusID] [int] NULL,
[City] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[StateID] [int] NULL,
[Zip] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[CountryID] [int] NULL,
[ContactName] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
[ContactPhone] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
[ContactPhoneExt] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
[ContactEmail] [nvarchar](500) NULL
```

)

```
SELECT @Return =
case when l.ContactFirstName +' ' +l.ContactLastName <> @LocationUpdate.ContactName then 1 else 0 END
+ CASE WHEN l.ContactEmail <> @LocationUpdate.ContactEmail THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
+ CASE WHEN l.ContactPhone <> @LocationUpdate.ContactPhone THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
+ CASE WHEN l.StatusID <> @LocationUpdate.StatusID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
+ CASE WHEN l.Zip <> @LocationUpdate.Zip THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
@Cleared = ISNULL(luh.Cleared, 0)
FROM @LocationUpdate lu, Location l
LEFT JOIN LocationUpdateHistory luh ON @LocationUpdate.ID = luh.idx
WHERE l.TrialID = @TrialID
AND l.City = @LocationUpdate.City
AND l.FacilityName = @LocationUpdate.FacilityName
```

Answer (score 3):

Explicit joins have precedence over comma joins. In your query you are effectively joining `LocationUpdateHistory` to `Location` alone, not to a cross-join of `@LocationUpdate` and `Location`, therefore you can't reference `lu`.

One possible solution is to replace the comma join with `CROSS JOIN`, then the `lu` alias will be accessible in your `ON` clause.

<s>But you likely need also to provide some condition for joining `Location` with `LocationUpdateHistory` and/or `@LocationUpdate` with `Location`.</s>

Seems like you already have all the necessary conditions, only you are keeping them in the `WHERE` clause. So, just convert the comma join + `WHERE` into another explicit join:

```
...
FROM @LocationUpdate lu
  INNER JOIN Location l ON l.City = lu.City
                       AND l.FacilityName = lu.FacilityName
  LEFT JOIN LocationUpdateHistory luh ON lu.ID = luh.idx
WHERE l.TrialID = @TrialID
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll try this out later and see how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

In select part of your query enclose name of your var into square brackets or use table aliasing

Brackets

```
SELECT @Return =
case when l.ContactFirstName +' ' +l.ContactLastName <> [@LocationUpdate].ContactName then 1 else 0 END
+ CASE WHEN l.ContactEmail <> [@LocationUpdate].ContactEmail THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
+ CASE WHEN l.ContactPhone <> [@LocationUpdate].ContactPhone THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
+ CASE WHEN l.StatusID <> [@LocationUpdate].StatusID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
+ CASE WHEN l.Zip <> [@LocationUpdate].Zip THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
@Cleared = ISNULL(luh.Cleared, 0)
FROM @LocationUpdate , Location l
LEFT JOIN LocationUpdateHistory luh ON [@LocationUpdate].ID = luh.idx
WHERE l.TrialID = @TrialID
AND l.City = [@LocationUpdate].City
AND l.FacilityName = [@LocationUpdate].FacilityName
```

Alias

```
SELECT @Return =
case when l.ContactFirstName +' ' +l.ContactLastName <> lu.ContactName then 1 else 0 END
+ CASE WHEN l.ContactEmail <> lu.ContactEmail THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
+ CASE WHEN l.ContactPhone <> lu.ContactPhone THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
+ CASE WHEN l.StatusID <> lu.StatusID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
+ CASE WHEN l.Zip <> lu.Zip THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
@Cleared = ISNULL(luh.Cleared, 0)
FROM @LocationUpdate lu, Location l
LEFT JOIN LocationUpdateHistory luh ON lu.ID = luh.idx
WHERE l.TrialID = @TrialID
AND l.City = lu.City
AND l.FacilityName = lu.FacilityName
```

**AND**

Try also to unwrap your joins and use TOP 1 (for clearness) where assign to variable

```
SELECT TOP 1 
  @Return =
case when l.ContactFirstName +' ' +l.ContactLastName <> lu.ContactName then 1 else 0 END
+ CASE WHEN l.ContactEmail <> lu.ContactEmail THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
+ CASE WHEN l.ContactPhone <> lu.ContactPhone THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
+ CASE WHEN l.StatusID <> lu.StatusID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
+ CASE WHEN l.Zip <> lu.Zip THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
@Cleared = ISNULL(luh.Cleared, 0)
FROM @LocationUpdate lu
JOIN Location l
  ON 
      l.City = lu.City
  AND l.FacilityName = lu.FacilityName
LEFT JOIN LocationUpdateHistory luh ON lu.ID = luh.idx
WHERE l.TrialID = @TrialID
```

Comment: And also don't mix implicit and explicit joins. Might be the reason why their attempt at using an alias mentioned in the question didn't work.

Comment: I've hit the reputation cap for today, so, please, revote me tomorrow 8-)